# C# wait for shell command to return while reading async

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I need to run an external process from a C# app, but wait for it to return before continuing execution. At the same time, I need to get and update a text box with progress info from stdout. Since the command may run for a few minutes and print info during that time, displaying that is absolutely necessary; but multiple commands are likely to be run and must be in order, so waiting is as well.

I attempted using:

```
p = Process.Start();
p.BeginOutputReadLine();
p.WaitForExit();
```

but that froze the UI thread while waiting and prevented the output from appearing. This:

```
p.Start();
p.BeginOutputReadLine();

while (!p.HasExited)
{
    Application.DoEvents();
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

works better, but is completely wrong/a bad idea and doesn't actually wait the full period.

I also briefly attempted using a BackgroundWorker to launch the shell process, but I'm not sure how to make the UI thread wait without blocking for the worker to finish.

What I want to do is provide a `DialogResult ShellExecute(String cmd)` similar to `ShowDialog()` that returns an OK/Cancel(/fail) result, if the user allowed the command to complete, clicked cancel, or the command's return code. It shouldn't return until the command has completed (or been canceled).

All the shell commands are run with:

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true,

    FileName = "cmd.exe",
    Arguments = "/c " + command
};
```

to redirect the output and effectively shell execute the command.

How would I go about correctly making a function that launches an async process, but still waits until that is finished to return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reworked most of the code to get this to work correctly.

The `ProgressForm` class provides a `QueueCommand` method, taking the desired shell command and pre/post delegates. When shown, the progress form uses a background worker to execute each command, handle the return code and execute the next command if appropriate.

The background worker waits for each shell command to finish (`Process.WaitForExit()`) while asynchronously feeding the UI thread output. When finished, it calls a method enabling the successful/ok button and hiding the progress bar.

```
void m_Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    int exec = 1;
    while (CommandQueue.Count > 0)
    {
        if (e.Cancel)
        {
            e.Result = 1;
            return;
        }

        WriteLine("Running command {0}, {1} remaining.", exec++, CommandQueue.Count);
        StagedCommand command = CommandQueue.Peek();
        try
        {
            if (command.Pre != null) command.Pre();
            int result = ShellExec(command.Command);
            if (command.Post != null) command.Post();
            CommandQueue.Dequeue();
            if (result != 0)
            {
                e.Result = result;
                return;
           }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            WriteLine("Error: {0}", exc.Message);
            e.Result = 1;
            return;
        }
    }

    WriteLine("All commands executed successfully.");
    e.Result = 0;
    return;
}

    int ShellExec(String command)
    {
        WriteLine(command);
        Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;

        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            UseShellExecute = false,
            LoadUserProfile = true,
            ErrorDialog = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            StandardErrorEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,

            FileName = "cmd.exe",
            Arguments = "/c " + command
        };

        Process shell = new Process();
        shell.StartInfo = info;
        shell.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        shell.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(ShellErrorDataReceived);
        shell.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(ShellOutputDataReceived);

        shell.Start();
        shell.BeginErrorReadLine();
        shell.BeginOutputReadLine();
        shell.WaitForExit();

        return shell.ExitCode;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Create your process from a ProcessStartInfo,

Clarification: ProcessStartinfo si needs something like

```
si.CreateNoWindow=true;
si.RedirectStandardOutput=true;
si.RedirectStandardError=true;
si.StandardOutputEncoding=Encoding.UTF8;
si.StandardErrorEncoding=Encoding.UTF8;
si.WindowStyle=ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
```

then before

```
p.Start();
```

use

```
p.OutoutDataReceived+=OutputHandler;
```

with

```
private static void OutputHandler(object theProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs evtdata)
{
  //evtdata.Data has the output data
  //use it, display it, or discard it
}
```

Comment: Obviously if you want to capture data from StdErr you have to repeat the exercise with p.ErrorDataReceievd+=ErrorHandler

Comment: This doesn't prevent the function creating and launching the process from returning. I have output redirected successfully, I'm focused more on the wait-without-blocking.